# Can I simplify my django database where I have many similar views (i.e. create, list) for many different models

Tags: python, django, view

I have several models with similar views...  Is there a way to write one list/create/detail view and apply that single view to all of my models?

```
def modelalist(request):
    objects = ModelA.objects.all()
    context = {
        "objects": objects,
    }
    return render(request, "app/modelalist.html", context)

def modelblist(request):
    objects = ModelB.objects.all()
    context = {
        "objects": objects,
    }
    return render(request, "app/modelblist.html", context)

# and on and on....
```

What's best practice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/). If you use the built-in class-based views [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) there is little code duplication.

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class ModelAList(ListView):
    model = ModelA
    template_name = 'app/modelblist.html'


class ModelBList(ListView):
    model = ModelB
    template_name = 'app/modelblist.html'
```

`template_name` is optional if you use the default value `"[app_name]/[model_name]_list.html"`. This requires you to rewrite your urls as well:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('...', modelalist, name='...'),           # old
    url('...', ModelAList.as_view(), name='...')  # new
]
```

The last difference is in the templates where the context variable `objects` is now `object_list`.

Comment: To be specific, [generic class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/)

Comment: This is pretty useful. Is it a better practice to just write views out separately or try something like this? @DanielHepper

Comment: @RuthYoung Django's generic class based views allow you to get stuff done with less code, and writing less code is generally a good thing. However, they are not a solution for everything. In some cases, it might be simpler to just write your own view.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, I would assume you could do something like the following:

```
def list_model(request, model_class, template, **kwargs):
  objects = model_class.object.all(**kwargs)
  context = {
      "objects": objects,
  }
  return render(request, template, context)
```

And then call it for your other models:

```
def modelalist(request):
  return list_model(request, ModelA, "app/modelalist.html")

def modelblist(request):
  return list_model(request, ModelB, "app/modelblist.html")
```

If all your templates are in a standard place, you could probably refactor that away as well.

Answer (score -1):

The handmade solution:

```
# views.py 
import os
from django.apps import apps

def modellist(request, app_label model_name):
    model = apps.get_model(app_label, model_name)
    objects = model.objects.all()
    template = os.path.join(app_label, "{}list.html".format(model_name)
    context = {
        "objects":objects,
        }
    return render(request, template, context)

# urls.py
   urlpatterns = [
       url(r"^(?P<app_label>\w+)/(?P<model_name)\w+/", views.modellist, name="modellist")
   ]
```

But I definitely **would NOT** do such a thing.

Comment: is it normal practice to just write out each view individually? I'm very new to Django - so I don't know best practices

Comment: @RuthYoung well for a basic crud you already have the `admin` app, and for any other real-life project you almost never have such simplistic needs so the mere idea of a "generic" view is mostly nonsense actually. Even the idea of a one-to-one mapping between views and models is something I've never seen in any of the dozens django projects I've worked on.